# Is it possible to use Address and Match functions inside another formula in order to find a column by name on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet that I use to compile weekly reports.  I paste the contents of each report into a new sheet in the spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet has an "Overview" sheet that uses formulas to pull counts and averages from other sheets in the spreadsheet.

Sometimes columns are added or removed from the source report, which means that the field shown in column "AO" in one sheet may be in column "AM" in a different sheet.  Because of this, I'm trying to use the column names (e.g., "Channel", "Time to first reply (seconds)", etc...) as a way to find the data so it can be displayed on the "Overview" sheet.

For example, one formula from the "Overview" sheet is this:
`=IFERROR(averageif(M1W5!$AO:$AO,"desktop",M1W5!$AJ:$AJ)/60)`

It looks at sheet "M1W5", then looks at the AO column to find all rows with the value "desktop", then it looks at that same row in the AJ column, and provides an average of all occurrences (meaning it averages up all values in the AJ column where AO = "desktop").

The problem I'm running into is this:
Because the columns frequently change between sheets (column AO on sheet "M1W5" may be column AM on sheet "M2W1", etc...), I need a way to find the columns by name (row 1 of every column in every sheet contains the column name) rather than by column letter.

Is there a way to do that?

So far I've been trying to use Address and Match functions to look up the column by column name.

For example, I can use this formula on the "Overview" sheet and it will give me the exact column from sheet "M1W5" that is named "Time to first reply (seconds)":

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Time to first reply (seconds)",M1W5!$A$1:$BZ$1,0),4),1,"")`

I can't figure out how (or if it's even possible) to use that inside another formula though.  For example, replacing the column letters

`M1W5!$AO:$AO`

with the address function like so:

`M1W5!SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Time to first reply (seconds)",M1W5!$A$1:$BZ$1,0),4),1,""):SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Time to first reply (seconds)",M1W5!$A$1:$BZ$1,0),4),1,"")`

Comment: It doesn't seem very clear to me what you need to achieve. I suggest you ask two types of questions *only* and separately. One type is application based: define your inputs, desired outputs; define their (e.g. positional) relations; and enhance clarity with text-based examples e.g. with a shared editable example sheet. Another type is pure programming based -- ie. why a function behaves in a certain way; how does one achieve this type of transformation etc. Your question mixes the two. As I read it, it's not clear what you are trying to. It's also not clear what technology problems you have.

Comment: (And I get a sense that the underlying problem isn't difficult. But your question is.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I've tried to explain it better.

Comment: Maybe include an example sheet?